# about override run() method of GUI in main method

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, runnable

The issue is when I close my GUI windows I wanna run a last method ( for example printList() ) but I couldn't manage to do it. This is my main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                patientTest2 screen = new patientTest2();
                screen.setVisible(true);
                screen.setResizable(false);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(patientTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    });
```

patientTest2 is my JFrame class. I assume that if I put `printList()` before `} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {` it should work and finally print my list to a file but it doesn't. I will be glad if you can help me and explain why of course_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a listener that extends `WindowAdapter` to your frame, and override the method `windowClosing(WindowEvent e)`. In this method, you will be able to call any methods you want to call before the window is closed.

Comment: yeap it worked and i feel very stupid cause i remember i add windowsClosed method and it didnt work so i didnt try windowsClosing. by the way thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to

- change the default close operation to `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` (if the window is a JFrame)
- add a WindowListener to your top-level window
- listen for window closing events, calling your method
- and then finally exit the JVM with the appropriate exit code (usually 0 if no errors).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have something that runs when you Java VM gets shut down, then you should have a look at

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //The stuff you want to do at shutdown.
        }
    }));
```

Please read the [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) for further information.

You also should set the DefaultCloseOperation of your Window if you want to close your Programm (and shutdown your Java VM) when the JFrame is closed.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This is I think what you were asking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the shut-down hook.  It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  Please roll it back if you disagree. Otherwise, vote for the RFE.  ;)